# How to calcualate memory usage of Desktop enviornment

Tags: unity, memory-usage, free

I'm using `Ubuntu 17.04` in my laptop.

`free -m` command gave me the following output after i logged in to my PC and ran this command.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-pc:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3865        1527        1171         249        1167        1862
Swap:          2047           0        2047
```

How can i calculate the memory usage of Desktop environment(`Unity`) after deducting the buffer and cache.

[Answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770108/what-do-the-changes-in-free-output-from-14-04-to-16-04-mean) like this are bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These tools show the memory usage of all running processes (for example when you are running Ubuntu with Unity, but no particular application program running).

### `free`

I am also using

```
free -m  # Display the amount of memory in megabytes.
```

and I think the column 'used' is useful (no pun intended).

The output of `free` is explained in the manual

```
man free
```

> DESCRIPTION
>          free displays the total amount of free and used physical and swap memory in the system, as well
>          as the buffers and caches used by the kernel. The information is gathered by parsing /proc/mem‐
>          info. The displayed columns are:
>
> total
>
> Total installed memory (MemTotal and SwapTotal in /proc/meminfo)
>
> used
>
> Used memory (calculated as total - free - buffers - cache)
>
> free
>
> Unused memory (MemFree and SwapFree in /proc/meminfo)
>
> shared
>
> Memory used (mostly) by tmpfs (Shmem in /proc/meminfo, available on kernels 2.6.32, displayed as zero if not available)
>
> buffers
>
> Memory used by kernel buffers (Buffers in /proc/meminfo)
>
> cache
>
> Memory used by the page cache and slabs (Cached and Slab in /proc/meminfo)
>
> buff/cache
>
> Sum of buffers and cache
>
> available
>
> Estimation of how much memory is available for starting new applications, without  swapping.  Unlike  the  data  provided  by  the  cache or free fields, this field takes into account page cache and also that not all reclaimable memory slabs will be reclaimed  due to  items  being  in use (MemAvailable in /proc/meminfo, available on kernels 3.14, emulated on kernels 2.6.27+, otherwise the same as free)

### `top`

`top` will show the same (or almost the same) result (tested in 16.04 LTS), (but in older versions the output of top was more difficult to match to the output of `free`).

### `htop`, more user friendly

You will get a similar result as 'used' with `htop` installed with

```
sudo apt install htop
```

Comment: Actually i have installed GNOME desktop environment in Ubuntu. By default unity is also there. I checked the memory usage of Unity without opening any other app after reboot and got 999 MB usage. Also in GNOME Wayland it was 1086 MB. Looks like these are such a huge memory utilization. So i just doubt if my calculations was right or not. Is this a normal utilization ? Please advice.

Comment: These desktop environments need a lot of RAM and a fairly modern graphics chip/card to work well. If your hardware cannot perform well or you need the RAM for other purposes, you can try an Ubuntu community flavour with a lighter desktop environment, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu.

Comment: Try them live and install the version that you like best. It is possible to install the desktop environments in the same Ubuntu system, but I think it is a bad idea, because it is very difficult to get a clean system after the testing. Instead test with live systems booted from USB and then install a separate system (dual boot) with the Ubuntu flavour you like best alongside the old system or replace the old system.

Comment: `free -m` shows **used 663 MiB** directly after booting Ubuntu 17.10  Gnome with Wayland in my Intel NUC with simple Intel graphics. `free -m` shows **used 270 MiB** directly after booting Lubuntu 17.10 (64-bit, the 32-bit version needs less RAM) in my Toshiba laptop, also with simple Intel graphics. `free -m` shows **used 1339 MiB** in this computer (my production computer with an nvidia graphics card running Lubuntu with several tabs in Firefox plus Thunderbird and some terminal windows open).

Comment: Okay, so i guess for me its better to switch to Lubuntu as i am using an old laptop with less amount of memory installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68232/discussion-between-sudodus-and-rooney).