# What does the available section in free -m command output mean on Ubuntu 18.04 server?

Tags: 18.04, server, memory-usage, free

On a testing server, Elasticsearch is giving this error:

`Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::ServiceUnavailable ([503] {"error":{"root_cause":[],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[]},"status":503})`

although the service is running fine.

Check whether Elasticsearch service running OK or not:

[image: Check whether Elasticsearch service running OK or not]

Then I saw that the memory usage and suspect it to be because of less than the required memory.

Check memory profile:

```
:~#free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          14681        9716         250        1487        4714        3316
Swap:             0           0           0
```

What is the `available` memory in the above output? Can we make use of it?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/158442). Copy the text here and use code formatting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do the changes in \`free\` output from 14.04 to 16.04 mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770108/what-do-the-changes-in-free-output-from-14-04-to-16-04-mean)

Comment: Your memory consumptions looks fine, there is nothing you can and should do about it. You should ask about the error and give details on that instead of what **you** think might be its cause. (See also [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Not sure though if askubuntu is the right place.

Comment: Also there might be people having the same issue, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157466/all-shards-failed